# What is wrong with my or function in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

This or function is not operative as the declaration is showing on all products and not just those listed here. What am I doing incorrectly?

```
   add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' , 'bbloomer_add_below_prod_gallery', 5 );
function bbloomer_add_below_prod_gallery() {
global $product;
$id = $product->id;
if($id==5735 || 9212 || 5782 || 5781 || 5775 || 5770 || 5764 || 5757 || 5752 || 574 || 5740 || 5725){
   echo '<div class="woocommerce-product-gallery" style="padding: 1em 2em; clear:left;">';
   echo '<center><h2>Conversion Chart</h2></center><img class="conversion" src="https://www.tattiniboots.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/conversion-1.png">';
   echo '</div>';
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to repeat `$id==number` each time, but it's better to put those number in a array and then use `in_array` function like so:

```php
$myValues=[5735, 9212, 5782, 5781, 5775, 5770, 5764, 5757, 5752, 574, 5740, 5725];
if(in_array($id, $myValues)){...}
```

Comment: Perfection. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your If statements are wrong. When using or ||  you should do them like this

$id == 123 || $id == 456